# Doing a make on OSX using Xcode 4.5.2 with the Makefile supplied with PhoneGap 2.3.0 doesn't create the PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg file

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.5

I downloaded the latest version of Phonegap for IOS and ran "make" from Terminal.  I ran make in the following subdir.

phonegap-2.3.0/lib/ios

I get these two lines back on stdout:

Xcode.app:      '/Applications/Xcode.app'
Using Developer folder: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

and my shell prompt is back.

However, no PhoneGapLibInstaller.pkg file is created as it describes on the github site instructions.

https://github.com/infil00p/phonegap-iphone

The file wasn't in my ios directory but when I did a search on my entire hard drive there is nothing there. I wanted to check in case it put it in the Xcode.app package contents for some reason.

In case this make file did something other than in the guides and actually worked, I loaded Xcode but PhoneGap doesn't show up as a Framework/template to choose from when making a new package.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks,
Dano

Answer (score 0):

That Github repo is from 3 years ago. You would probably be better off looking at the actual current documentation.

Adobe "value add" distribution page: http://phonegap.com
Docs: http://docs.phonegap.com

Latest Cordova information (the open source project PhoneGap is based on): http://cordova.apache.org/

Current Github: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios